# Can't typecast 'void*' to 'double*' nor 'float*' using C language

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

Sorry if this question already have a solution over there somewhere, but all answers of similar questions I found wasn't helping me.

```
void imprimePilhaDouble (void *vetor, int tam)
{
    int i;
    double *vetorDouble;

    vetorDouble = (double*) vetor;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
    {
        printf("%e\t", *((double*) vetorDouble[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void imprimePilhaFloat (void *vetor, int tam)
{
    int i;
    float *vetorFloat;

    vetorFloat = (float*) vetor;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
    {
        printf("%f\t", *((float*) vetorFloat[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The code above is returning these errors when compiled:

```
In function 'imprimePilhaDouble'
erro: cannot convert to a pointer type
In function 'imprimePilhaFloat'
erro: cannot convert to a pointer type
```

For the lines `printf("%e\t", *((double*) vetorDouble[i]));` and `printf("%f\t", *((float*) vetorFloat[i]));` respectively.
Is there any way to stop those errors? I made another similar function that seems to work right:

```
void imprimePilhaInteiro (void *vetor, int tam)
{
    int i, *vetorInt;

    vetorInt = (int*) vetor;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\t", *((int*) vetorInt[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It looks okay.  Did you transcribe it here correctly?  Which compiler?

Comment: `vetorDouble[i]` is a `double`, so you're casting a `double` to a `double*`...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this line:

```
printf("%e\t", *((double*) vetorDouble[i]));
```

tries to cast a `double` to a `double *`.  You can't cast a floating point value to a pointer, thus you get the error you report.  The same thing happens with your `float` function.

When you cast an `int` to an `int *`, that doesn't cause an error, but is pretty much nonsense.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

vetor is a `(void *)`.

vetorDouble is casted to `(double *)`

vectorDouble[i] is in fact `*(vetorDouble + i)`, i.e. **what is pointed to by the base address vetorDouble with an offset of (i) * size of (double)**, because vetorDouble is of type `(* double)`.

So, vetorDouble[i] is `*(vectorSouble+i)`.

**It is already a double**. You don't need to cast it to a `(double*)` again, and the compiler is right when it tells you you can't convert a double to a (double*): it has no meaning.

So, you must write:

```
void imprimePilhaDouble (void *vetor, int tam)
{
    double *vetorDouble = (double*) vetor;

    for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
    {
        printf("%e\t", vetorDouble[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

You can even write (because, readingthe name of your function, it await a double):

```
void imprimePilhaDouble (double *vetorDouble, int tam)
{
    for (i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
        printf("%e\t", vetorDouble[i]);

    printf("\n");
}
```